# x64Dbg view jumps to selected command

Tags: x64dbg

I've poked around the settings for x64dbg and never managed to find this. I was just wondering if there was an option for x64dbg similar to ollydbg's "show jumps to selected command":

[image]

[image]

Thanks all

Comment: care to explain what does this option do? I'm assuming it does not control if the jump lines/arrows are displayed as those you have in x64dbg too.

Answer (score 1):

To do this in x64dbg you can use the side bar on the left, which shows jump paths that are within the current view. You can also run the command “xanalyze” to do xref analysis, which will then show the jump source lines for xrefs.

Comment: Is there any way to click on the command and see on the left if there is a jump path to it from an instruction out of current view? Or is xanalyze the way to go? Thanks a lot and I truly appreciate the work you've put in to making the program.

Comment: No, the view on the left is a clone of IDA. With xrefs it would be possible to show arrows coming from higher up, but it would make everything too crowded probably...